# Fitting SHIMANO GRX FC-RX600 46/30 Chainset (11spd) to a road bike

Tags: chain, grx

Is it possible to fit the cyclocross GRX 48/31 chain set to a road bike? I have a SRAM Red eTap shifting on my road bike. This restricts me to a 10-28 cassette. I am about to take on a very hilly sportive and it will cost nearly £500 to updates the rear derailleur to take a 10-32 cassette.

So I was wondering if I could fit a GRX chain set to the front of my road bike so that I could reduce the smallest gear to 31/28.

Comment: I do not know the real limitations of SRAM Red eTap (therefore comment not answer), but the (mechanical) derailleurs I encountered so far have some wiggle room for wider cassettes. My (2x) GRX rear derailleur officially only supports up to 11-34, but reportedly -36 or even -38 works just as well. With a hanger extension I now run it totally fine with a 11-42 cassette on my gravel bike. Your mileage may vary, but experimenting with with wider cassettes and perhaps hanger extensions could be cheaper and less hassle than changing the chainset.

Comment: Unfortunately the original Etap has a full limit of 28 tooth cog.

Answer (score 4):

This is a good question. Gearing for road bikes has evolved considerably from the 1990s to the 2010s. In my opinion, this question shows a continuing gap in the available gearing, specifically the availability of sub-compact cranks (I.e. under 50/34 front gearing).

You can physically fit the GRX crank, but it will definitely require a new bottom bracket. You probably have a GXP crankset, which uses a 24mm spindle that steps down to 22mm on one side, and the associated bottom bracket. I am inferring this from you saying Red eTap, rather than RED AXS. Shimano uses a straight 24mm spindle.

Additionally, the GRX chainline is about 2.5mm wider than Shimano road cranks, I.e. the center of the chainrings is offset away from the bike. Your SRAM front derailleur was most assuredly not designed with this in mind. It may not have enough lateral travel to change chainrings. There is no compatible SRAM FD for 11s eTap, whereas if you had Shimano you could at least mount a mechanical GRX derailleur.

Unfortunately, while there are some third party cranks which can take sub-compact chainrings and have a road chainline, they tend to be pretty expensive, e.g. White Industries, Rotor. There may be some budget options like FSA.

Shimano has not shown any interest in sub-compact gearing for its road groups, although it has those options for gravel groups. Campagnolo Chorus, but not the higher two groups, has a 48/32 crank option. SRAM doesn’t make as sharp a distinction between its road and gravel groups, but its AXS Wide 43/30 cranks come close. These do use a gravel chainline, though.

Comment: *There may be some budget options like FSA.* Yep:  https://shop.fullspeedahead.com/en/cranksets/road/tempo-adventure-crankset

Comment: A Hollowtech bottom bracket certainly is a step up from horrible GXP bottom brackets.

Comment: Have a look at Shimano FC-CX-50 crank sets. They come with 46-36. However, they are 110 BCD spiders, you may mount any chain ring larger than 33t. CX-50 is about 105 level, has road chain line, and like GRX 24 mm spindles. CX-50 are 10sp, but that doesn't matter with the front derailleur.

Comment: @gschenk With the 36 lower chainring one gets pretty limited in the low gears. That is the opposite what one is normally aiming for with subcompacts. These CX cranks are aimed at CX racing where you run the steep hills with the bike on your shoulders but are not good for road/gravel traveling where lower gears are needed.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава no need to use the original chain rings simply replace them. It's 5 bolt 110 BCD. Smallest one that fits is an oval 32t ring. Less exotic would be a 32t round.

Comment: OK, but that is still not within that desire 28-31 range.

Comment: Also, 32t round rings don’t fit on most 110mm bcd cranks. They conflict slightly with the spider. Praxis notes this for their own cranks, warning that their 32t ring will only fit certain of their cranks.

Answer (score 3):

SRAM sells an direct Mount Red Force AXS Spider (Parts Number 11.6118.062.001) without powermeter allowing you to install assymetric 94mm chainrings on your crank.
Fitting chainrings from SRAM would be 43/30.
This will be easier and most likely cheaper than changing to a new crankset.